# Field being used in two Validation Rule in Salesforce

Tags: validation, configuration, validation-rule

Requirement is to use "Status" field in validation rule and "Status" is being used in two validation rule which is blocking each other when we activate both rules at a time.

**Requirement - 1**
User needs to change "Status" to **Deactivated** if prior value of "Status" was **Draft** or **Pending Approval** or **Rejected**.

Validation Rule - 1

```
AND(
    NOT(OR(
    PRIORVALUE(Status__c) = 'Draft',
    PRIORVALUE(Status__c) = 'Pending Approval',
    PRIORVALUE(Status__c) = 'Rejected'
    )),
    TEXT(Status__c) <> 'Deactivated'
  )
```

Above solution is working perfect only when we have only this rule is Activated.

**Requirement - 2**
Status, Status Category, Start Date, End Date fields.

User needs to change "Status" to **Blocked** if prior value of "Status" was **Approved** and "Status Category" was **Request** or if prior value of "Status" was **Saturated** and "Status Category" was **Expired** and Today's date is falling in between "Start Date" & "End Date".

Validation Rule - 2

```
AND(
      NOT(AND(
        AND(Start_Date__c <= TODAY(), End_Date__c >= TODAY()),
        OR(
        TEXT(Status_Category__c) = 'Request',
        TEXT(Status_Category__c) = 'Expired'
        ),
        OR(
        PRIORVALUE(Status__c) = 'Approved',
        PRIORVALUE(Status__c) = 'Saturated'     
        )
      )),
    TEXT(Status__c) <> 'Blocked'
  )
```

Again the above solution is working perfect only when we have only this rule is Activated.

**Problem**
Now the problem arise when we activate both rules in system or else we combine both rules in a single rule.

If Requirement - 1 is satisfied in system then no need to check Requirement - 2.
I am looking for a solution like this - If(Requirement -1, true, Requirement - 2).

Below is the Single Validation rule in which i have combined both Requirement - 1 & 2 into single rule.

```
OR(
  AND(
    NOT(OR(
    PRIORVALUE(Status__c) = 'Draft',
    PRIORVALUE(Status__c) = 'Pending Approval',
    PRIORVALUE(Status__c) = 'Rejected'
    )),
    TEXT(Status__c) <> 'Deactivated'
  ),
  AND(
      NOT(AND(
        AND(Start_Date__c <= TODAY(), End_Date__c >= TODAY()),
        OR(
        TEXT(Status_Category__c) = 'Request',
        TEXT(Status_Category__c) = 'Expired'
        ),
        OR(
        PRIORVALUE(Status__c) = 'Approved',
        PRIORVALUE(Status__c) = 'Saturated'     
        )
      )),
    TEXT(Status__c) <> 'Blocked'
  )
)
```

In general salesforce doesn't recommend If Else or nest If Else in to be used in validation rule.

Looking for some suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked into your individual rules or combined one in detail..

but tried to literally map your requirement statements in to the below rule..

```
IF(
    AND(
        OR(
            PRIORVALUE(Status__c) = 'Draft',
            PRIORVALUE(Status__c) = 'Pending Approval',
            PRIORVALUE(Status__c) = 'Rejected'
        ),
        TEXT(Status__c) != 'Deactivated'
    ), 
    TRUE,
    AND(
        OR( 
            AND(
                PRIORVALUE(Status__c) = 'Approved',
                TEXT(Status_Category__c) = 'Request'
            ),
            AND(
                PRIORVALUE(Status__c) = 'Saturated',     
                TEXT(Status_Category__c) = 'Expired'
            )
        ),
        AND(Start_Date__c <= TODAY(), End_Date__c >= TODAY()),
        TEXT(Status__c) <> 'Blocked'        
    )
)
```

Simplifying the rule :

IF

prior value of status is one of the 3 and current value is not Deactivated

ELSE

the combo of prior status and current status category along with current date and current status

Comment: Else is not working If is working but i have added NOT() in surrounding of OR()  in if condition.

Comment: I hv update the OR to IF so if rule 1 happens it returns TRUE and wont evaluate rule 2. if rule 1 is false, then it will get into rule 2.. see if it works

Comment: I tried to use the updated Solution provided by you but none of the IF & ELSE is working. So, i tried to change IF to be modified to work as NOT(OR(condition)), TEXT(Apttus__Status__c) <> 'Deactivated'.

Else condition is still not working. The reason behind this is once we try to evaluate ELSE the IF part is blocking.

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

```
  OR(((TEXT(PRIORVALUE(  Status__c ))='Draft'|| 
    TEXT(PRIORVALUE(  Status__c ))='Pending Approval'|| 
    TEXT(PRIORVALUE(  Status__c ))='Rejected')) 
    &&(TEXT(  Status__c )!='Deactivated') , 

   (((TEXT(PRIORVALUE(Status__c))='Approved'||
   TEXT(PRIORVALUE(Status__c))='Saturated') || 
   (TEXT(Status_Category__c )='Request'||
   TEXT(  Status_Category__c )='Expired') &&    
   (Start_Date__c <=today()&&  End_Date__c >= TODAY()))  && 
   TEXT(  Status__c )!='Blocked'))
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but this is an error prone and not working!!

Comment: @user2423706, We are missing the TEXT() in PRIORVALUE(). Try the above updated code above.

Comment: 1st condition is being satisfied and working as expected but 2nd one is causing problem and it's not working as expected.

Comment: @user2423706, So the 2nd rule is User should select blocked if the prior value of status is approved/saturated or the prior value of status category is expired/request and the date should fall between start and end date..Is this right?

Comment: Yes. You have interpreted right. So, this 2nd one is not working.

Comment: @user2423706 As I have told,  updated again and checked in my dev org.its working fine!!! Try the updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27183/discussion-between-anitha-j-j-and-user2423706).